# Object appears as existing and not at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got some very strange issue which I cannot debug.

This is my code:

```
def find_order_and_payment
  @payment = Spree::Payment.find_by_identifier(params['session_id'])
  Rails.logger.info "payment_id #{@payment.id}"
  @order = @payment.order
end
```

And this is the output:

```
I, [2014-01-17T16:39:43.084827 #12342]  INFO -- : payment_id 187
I, [2014-01-17T16:39:43.090718 #12332]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 448ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/payu_status_controller.rb:36:in `find_order_and_payment'
```

Line 36 is the line with `Rails.logger`. I don't understand, why I get correct `id`, but same line returns undefined method `id`? If I'll call above code from console everything works as expected.

Comment: We call that Schrödinger's Object. ;)

Comment: In all seriousness, is it possible that method is being called twice in a row, or something like that?

Comment: I would imagine you are calling find_order_and_payment twice.  The second call has no associated data and returns NoMethodError.

Comment: @Teeg: if I'll force two requests, then first fails as above and second in regular way (`Rails.logger` shows no id).

Comment: @zrl3dx To be specific, when you say "two requests" do you mean two HTTP requests from the browser, or do you mean two invocations of that method (within the same request)? From the log, it looks like the latter, rather than the former. Also, where does that method exist, and can you show us from where it is being called?

Comment: Where is the `find_order_and_payment` method (referenced in the error message) being called?